# Best approach for long db operations?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, multithreading, batch-processing

I have a script which does the following..

- fetches one record from db
- calls an external api ( from some otherserver on internet) and fetches data
- it reads data updated sql database (almost same records with updated values for a few columns)

so for,

- I am not using *, rather I query only required columns
- I am running script on off-peak times
- My environment is LocalHost running on current version of WAMP
- I got a server machine, and its okay, no issue with it

My Issue is,

I have a big db consisting of more than 14k records which needs to be updated daily ( some products for which I have to update cost and quantity). When the script runs , it runs for hours, and Then too, it never completes 14k records, rather stops at around 8k records updates..

- How can I manage this type of db operations?
- How can I split my db operations in two parts /  threads , so that each part / thread runs in parallel to other , in this way, I will be able to reduce the time to half. That's my main concern.
- What do you recommend for such situations?

Comment: If you run one record through this process, what is the part that takes the longest?

Comment: number or records, as they are so big, its take too long

Comment: 14k records is minuscule...

Comment: Your question is too vague, so we cannot help you. It would be best if you explained exactly how/when/where/etc you query the external API and your database, go into detail, show code snippets...

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, the DB times are not your problem. Even when using a fresh (non-prepared) statement each time, 14k records should not be a matter of hours (assuming an index exists for lookup).

(But of course you should confirm (measure) the db runtimes times, too, and of course you should use prepared statements.)

However, calling an external web service 14k times obviously takes quite some time! Does the external service provide a batch API? If not, I suggest that you try to keep the HTTP connection open (alive) when querying the server for further requests, in order to reduce network latencies.

As a last optimization, you could spawn a set of worker processes (or threads) that process the rows that you have fetched from the DB in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

- Create quite a few threads/sub-processes, say 20 or 50, in your db
  client side to update different sections of records in parallel;
  Monitor your CPU,IO,Memory on both client and server and see how much
  resources are utilized, if fine, increase the number.
- Batch commit in your db client side; Say, only commit after every 100 rows are updated;
- Make sure key columns are indexed in db server side;
- Always think of batch processing when working with large number of data records. This applies with db operations, web service, rest,  etc.
- Not sure about your business logic, you might want to make web service reading and db updating run in parallel too. In other words, while some external are being fetched by some threads, other threads are writing data to db.
- Yes, if one sql statement is executed repeatedly, using prepared statements is much better.
- You can also consider disable things like data referential integrity during the whole course, or set the db the enforce it when a commit command is issued. Combined with batch commit, this saves a lot of time in the db server side.